# Global functions in Flask fail with nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, global-variables, gunicorn

The following script is an attempt to run `python` random module with `flask`. The app works fine when served via `gunicorn`:

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app`

On the contrary, when allowing web requests through `nginx`, validation fails. What happens is that a new secret number is generated, thus causing a systematic discrepancy between the entered number and the stored one.

My question: what could be going wrong with `nginx` whereas the code works fine as tested with `gunicorn`? I am not aware of any errors stemming from the log files.

**The Flask view**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def gen_secret_number():
    return random.randint(1, 100)
    
secret_number = gen_secret_number()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def guess_number():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        entered_value = int(request.form['number'])

        if entered_value == secret_number:
            message = "Well done"
            return render_template('index.html', message=message)
        elif entered_value < secret_number:
            message = "Too small"
        else:
            message = "Too big"
        return render_template('index.html', secret_number=secret_number, message=message)

    return render_template('index.html', secret_number=secret_number, message=None)

@app.route('/reset', methods=['POST'])
def reset():
    global secret_number
    secret_number = gen_secret_number()
    return redirect(url_for('guess_number'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The **form**:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('guess_number') }}">
    <label for="number">Enter your number :</label>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="number" required>
    <button type="submit">Guess</button>
    <h4>{{ secret_number}}</h4>
</form>

<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('reset') }}">
    <button type="submit">Restart</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Using global variables and manipulating them is always tricky, you can use session for storing your random number instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close the issue, I am going to answer myself, after being guided by the comment of [@Sandeep Kulkarni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16885974/sandeep-kulkarni).
On the main view function (`guess_number()`), one should add:

```
if 'secret_number' not in session:
    session['secret_number'] = gen_secret_number()
```

In the reset function, one should replace `global secret_number`
with `session.pop('secret_number', None)` in order to start with a new number.

I would also recommend the reading of [Handling Global Variables in Flask](https://vivek-kaushal.medium.com/handling-global-variables-in-flask-36c5b4564792#:%7E:text=More%20often%20than%20not%2C%20what,for%20this%20functionality%20%3A%20Flask%20Sessions.).